# Asymptotic Limit of a Summation?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Find:
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\sqrt{\binom{n+k}{2}}}{n^2} $.

I am clueless how to solve this as I am unable to sandwich the above summation by two series which converge to the same limit (and hence use sandwich theorem). Neither do I know of any asymptotic approximation for the above summation, nor can I write the above summation as the Riemann sum of an integral. How do I proceed?

Edit: $\binom{n}{r}$ is the the binomial coefficient $^nC_r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\binom{n+k}{2}=\frac12(n+k)(n+k-1)$, in the limit we can use the fact that $\binom{n+k}{2}\approx\frac12(n+k)^2\implies\sqrt{\binom{n+k}{2}}\approx\frac{\sqrt2}2(n+k)$
$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\sqrt{\binom{n+k}{2}}}{n^2}=\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{\sqrt2}2\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{n+k}{n^2}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{\sqrt2}2\bigg(\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{n^2}\bigg)$$
$$=\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{\sqrt2}2\bigg(\frac1n(n)+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big(\frac12n(n+1)\Big)\bigg)$$
$$=\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{\sqrt2}2\bigg(1+\frac12(1+\frac1n)\bigg)$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt2}2\bigg(1+\frac12\bigg)=\frac{3\sqrt2}{4}$$

Comment: And if you want to get rid of the $\approx$ sign, you can just bound the square root of the binomial coefficient above and below:
$$\frac{(n+k-1)}{\sqrt{2}} \leq \sqrt{\binom{n+k}{2}} \leq \frac{(n+k)}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
Compute the sums using both bounds, and you'll find they converge to the same limit as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^11+x dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}n}\sum_{i=1}^n1+\frac{i-1}{n}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{(1+\frac{i-1}{n})(1+\frac{i}{n}) }\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}n}\sum_{i=1}^n1+\frac{i}{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^11+x dx $$

so the limit is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^11+x dx =\frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}$.